# Convert WKWebView to PDF / Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiwebview, wkwebview

I need to covert web page to PDF.

I want to come up with a way to covert web page to pdf with the original size that is shown while you are scrolling this page in browser on iPhone.

What I have done for now: converting webpage to PDF, but with printing format only.
Print option is not enough for me as the size of the page changes as for printing.

But what I would like to achieve is generating a PDF from a webpage in the same way how we can create a screenshot of the page and then create it as PDF. (so the original size and content is not changed and looks exactly how it looks on iPhone)

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import PDFKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    
    public func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        let url = URL(string: "\(searchBar.text!)")//zrobic opt bind if let+https if else
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(request)
    }
    

    @IBAction func convertButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
      
       let url : NSURL! = NSURL(string: "\(String(describing: webView.url))")!
        webView.load(NSURLRequest(url: url as URL) as URLRequest)
       
        let printFormatter = webView.viewPrintFormatter()
        let renderer = UIPrintPageRenderer()
        renderer.addPrintFormatter(printFormatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)
        
        
        let pageSize = CGSize(width: 595.2, height: 841.8) //set desired sizes
    
        let margin = CGFloat(20.0)
        
       
        renderer.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: CGRect(x: margin, y: margin, width: pageSize.width, height: pageSize.height - margin * 2.0)), forKey: "paperRect")
        renderer.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pageSize.width, height: pageSize.height)), forKey: "printableRect")
        
        
        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect.zero, nil)
        webView.drawHierarchy(in: webView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        
        for i in 0..<renderer.numberOfPages {
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
            renderer.drawPage(at: i, in: UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds())
        }
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

            let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("webview.pdf")
            try? pdfData.write(to: filePath, options: .atomic)
            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [filePath], applicationActivities: [])
            present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
       
    } 
}
```